# Read and Write UTF-8 characters from System.in stream

Tags: java, input, unicode, utf-8, inputstream

if i print unicode String like *ελληνικά* on the console using the `print` method of `System.out` stream, its printed as expected (As i use Ubuntu mono in my output console which supports UTF characters).

But if i try to read from the console unicode characters with UTF-8 encoding using System.in stream, it doesn't read properly.
 I have tried many different ways to achieve it using various reader classes with the System.in stream but it never works. So does anyone know a way i could do that

Here is a sample of code

```
BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
BufferedWriter console = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8"));

console.write("p1: Γίνεται πάντως\n");
console.flush();
System.out.println("p2: Γίνεται πάντως");

byte dataBytes[] = keyboard.readLine().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("p3: " + new String(dataBytes));
console.write("p4: " + new String(dataBytes, "UTF-8") + "\n");
console.flush();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

System.out.println("p5: " + (char) System.in.read());
System.out.println("p6: " + scan.nextLine());
System.out.println("p7: " + keyboard.readLine());
```

and the output on my console:

```
p1: Γίνεται πάντως
p2: Γίνεται πάντως
Δέν
p3: ���
p4: ���
Δέν
p5: Ä
p6: ��
Δέν
p7: ���
```

my IDE is Netbeans

Comment: Can you post your not working code please?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077178/how-can-i-make-system-in-input-stream-read-utf-8-characters)

Comment: I doubt the encoding of your `System.in` is `UTF-8`.

Comment: how can i check the encoding of System.in ? anyway the property "file.encoding" of System is UTF-8

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Is this the output of Netbeans console or your operating system console?

Answer (score 1):

`System.in` is an `InputStream`, which is a stream of bytes. You need a `Reader` to read characters. The reader is going to do the decoding for you.

In this case, you can wrap `System.in` with a `InputStreamReader`, passing "UTF-8" as the second constructor parameter.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
while (console.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(console.nextLine());
```

Update:

It's likely the encoding of your stdin is wrong. To verify, you can compare the byte array you get from `System.in` and the expected.

```
byte [] expected = "Δέν".getBytes("UTF-8"); // [-50, -108, -50, -83, -50, -67]

byte [] fromStdin = new byte[1024];
int c = System.in.read(fromStdin);
for (int i = 0; i < c-1; i++) {
    if (expected[i] != fromStdin[i]) {
        System.out.println(i + ", " + fromStdin[i]);
    }
}
```

And you input "Δέν" (without double quotes) then hit enter. If it outputs anything, your System.in is in wrong encoding.

> Shouldn't `System.in` have the same encoding as `defaultCharset` or some system property?

Not necessarily. It's a byte stream, not a character stream. It cannot be a character stream, because you can/should be able to feed it binary data. An image or audio or vedio, whatever you want. It must support those. That's why it's just an `InputStream`. **It depends on what the environment gave your program.** And I know very little about your environment. You need to find out how to change your environment, or figure out what encoding it's actually giving your program.

For example we have an `UTF-16` text file `utf16.txt`, and we feed its content to our program who expects the STDIN to be `UTF-8` encoded text:

```
java -cp ... our.utf8.Program < utf16.txt
```

It's going to read gibberish.

Comment: yes you are right. But how can i set the encoding of System.in?

Comment: But why the java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset() returns "UTF-8"? isn't that the encoding that System.in uses?

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: so as i see i have to set windows enviroment encoding? how can i do that?

Comment: You may want to try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Although i still can't read unicode with System.in. I followed what the answer instructed and now i have Code Page 65001 which is the utf-8 but i can't still input utf characters. I beleive its System.in problem as i can input unicode in batch

Answer (score 1):

Try using `java.io.Console.readLine()` or `java.io.Console.readLine(String, Object...)`. `Console` instance is returned by `System.console()` method. For example:

```
package package01;

import java.io.Console;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("No console");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String s = console.readLine("Enter string: ");
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: Using `Console` is probably the right way to go. However you should be aware that within IDEs [`System.console()` will return `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203646/4288506). It would probably be best to create a separate method for reading with a `Reader` parameter. Then you could call it with `System.console().reader()`, or try to create a reader based on `System.in` and even use a mock reader for unit tests.